# how to test the following Java method

Tags: java, unit-testing

Also just wanted to get a second opinion on the following code, if I have done it correctly. I have written a method that uses the `postCode` variable to create a multiplier for the variable `labourCharge` to increase this for expensive areas.

First I needed to write a public method `costMultiplier()` that takes no arguments and returns a double. The method should then return 1.2 for postcodes beginning “WC1A” or “EC1A”, and 1.0 otherwise.

```
public double costMultiplier() {
    if (postCode.startsWith("WC1A") || postCode.startsWith("EC1A")) {
        return 1.2; 
    }
    else 
        return 1.0;
```

I am basically creating a program that calculates the carpet cost and fitting. The main class is carpetestimator class and the variables are postcode and labourCharge. I am looking for a simple way to testing for e.g something like carpetestimator ce= new carpetestimator(4.0); ce.getlabourCharge();... so basically if I have coded it correctly, once I execute the statement above, the answer 0 will be displayed. That is how I want to test the code above.
    }

Comment: Does it work when you test it?

Comment: I don't know how to test it??

Comment: https://www.bluej.org/tutorial/testing-tutorial.pdf

Comment: How to test it? You use values that exercise all code paths. Unrelated, but the `else` is superfluous, and you should decide if you want to put single lines in blocks, or not, but not both. I'd also argue that this method would be better off as a utility that takes a value.

Comment: Hi Aaron - for providing a proper answer to this question, you maybe want to add a little more context, e.g. where the `postCode` variable comes from. If it is an object property of an object in which `costMultiplier` is an object method, it can be tested as described in Jagrut's answer below.

Comment: Hi Michael, I am creating a program that calculates the carpet cost and fitting. The main class is carpetestimator class and the variables are postcode and labourCharge. I am looking for a simple way to testing for e.g something like carpetestimator ce= new carpetestimator(4.0); ce.getlabourCharge();... so basically if I have coded it correctly, once I execute the statement above, the answer 0 will be displayed. That is how I want to test the code above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach to test your functionality and adapt it.

```
public class Sample {
    public double costMultiplier(String postCode) {
        if (postCode.startsWith("WC1A") || postCode.startsWith("EC1A")) {
            return 1.2;
        }
        else
            return 1.0;
    }
}
```

This is the test class that uses JUnit.

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SampleTest {
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        Sample s = new Sample();
        Assert.assertEquals(1.2, s.costMultiplier("WC1A"),0.00001);
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        Sample s = new Sample();
        Assert.assertEquals(1.2, s.costMultiplier("EC1A"),0.00001);
    }

    @Test
    public void test3() {
        Sample s = new Sample();
        Assert.assertEquals(1.0, s.costMultiplier("ABC"),0.00001);
    }
}
```

It is a good idea to add both positive and negative tests.

Reference to JUnit Assert API: http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/index.html?org/junit/Assert.html

Answer (score 0):

For this code you should have 3 test cases: "WC1A","EC1A" and any random string( to check that else condition works properly). Using junit5 `@ParameterizedTest` feature your test might look like this:

```
public class SampleTest {

    private Sample sample = new Sample();

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("getSource")
    void whenGetCostMultiplier_thenReturnCorrectValue(String input, double output) {
         sample.setCode(input);
         Assert.assertEquals(output, sample.costMultiplier());
    }

    private static Stream<Object> getSource() {
        return Stream.of(
                Arguments.of("WC1A", 1.2),
                Arguments.of("EC1A", 1.2),
                Arguments.of("ABC", 1.0)
        );
    }
}
```

Basically it takes `@MethodSource("getSource")` source and runs same test on each `Stream` element. This code will result to three test runs with different arguments.